# Copy/pasting feature in codeblocks

Tags: ide, codeblocks

I have installed **Code::Blocks 13.12 in my windows 8.1** but pasting input at runtime in the command line(I think it is called command line)doesn't seem to work.I have to type the whole input inorder to get output.Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

**P.S** :- I have tied ctrl+V as well as right click and paste but nothing really working in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the text that you want to paste. When C::B console runs, right-click on its top window border (where the name of the executable appears). This will produce a menu. Select **Edit** -> **Paste**, and the copied text will be pasted at the cursor in the console.